# How do I use flexbox to force content onto a new line when browser window is shrunk?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am relatively new to web dev, I am beginning to design my own websites for practice. I a, using flexbox and when I shrink my browser window, both items in my header class stay on the same line.

```
body {
  font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1050px;
  /* border: 1px solid grey; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  border-style: ridge;
}

.my-name {
  color: #13A8BC;
  flex: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  flex: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #13A8BC;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #5D12E7;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My First Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css\styling.css">
  </head>
  <div class="container">
  <body>
    <div class="header">
  <div class="my-name">
  <h2>Ryan Loughrey</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-items">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="about">About</a>
        <a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

[image: index.html]

I need the navbar to begin on a new line when window is shrunk, i.e. I need my current content to be more responsive.

Comment: `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: thank you, I have tried this, but I may be placing the line in the incorrect place, where would this line need to go?

Comment: Depends what you want to wrap, but I would assume `.header`

Comment: I have had the wrap in the .header, however when I shrink the navbar disappears and all you can see is my name. I am unsure where I have gone wrong with such minimal coding so far

Comment: you have set the width on 1050px so the elements inside will never get pushed by the window, for example if you set it at max-width:1050px and width:100% do you get the desired result? and flex-wrap:wrap in your header as Paulie mentioned

Comment: thank you, I have set width to auto, and now they seem to be getting pushed. Any recommendations to refine my code, or improve my layout so far? As I said I am a newbie just trying to improve so any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Layout is personal i guess but the common aproach is to add a hamburger menu instead of letting the objects push down:)

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will definitely take it on board!:)